# python: с сайта www.soccer24.com пытаюсь вытащить данные из таблиц - таблицу overall читает а home и away нет

Tags: python, python-3.x

буду очень признателен если подскажите где я напортачил - пытаюсь вытащить данные забитых и пропущенных мячей по имени команды - вот мой хавнокод

[код который работает на 1/3](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/0ep6jKIGAOqP-Q)

файл с кодом лучше скачать - чтоб увидеть правильную разметку кода